# check for null and end of stream in same statement

Tags: c#, streamreader

```
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null && !sr.EndOfStream)
```

This does not work.  It literally keeps looping and I get an exception because "line" is null, and the EndofStream has been reached.  Any idea?

Comment: What is the exact exception that you are getting?

Comment: Why are you using both !sr.EndOfStream and (line = sr.ReadLine()) != null ? Both of them mean As long as the end of file hasn't been reached. I guess you wanna skip the empty lines but this is not the right way, if so let me know to post the solution for skipping empty lines.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in the first place?  Just use `while(!sr.EndOfStream){var line = sr.ReadLine(); ...}` That's much more readable and easier to work with than what you have.

Comment: "while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)" was not working, it would still turn up null, so I added the !sr.EndOfStream, which also did not work.  It would say "object reference not set blah blah" when I would try to check a line.Contains(value), when "line" was null.  I ended up doing !sr.EndOfStream and then line = sr.Readline();

Comment: edit - can't really post readable code in comments i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put both checking together, code will escape looping even if `ReadLine()` is null before reaching `EndOfStream`. Following is a breakdown version but will go through the whole stream.

```
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
   if ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
      //do your work here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use the following, ReadLine will return `null` when end of file is reached, so checking for `EndOfStream` is not necessary.

```
while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Return Value
>   Type: System.String
>   The next line from the input stream, or null if the end of the input stream is reached.

Answer (score 0):

Use only this part

```
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   // your code
}
```

Comment: That won't compile.  A string is not implicitly convertable to a boolean.  (In C# anyway.)

Comment: hey, sorry... i am stupid, I forgot send a second part of conditions

Answer (score 0):

In case you'd like to skip the empty lines: a line in a text file cannot be Null, null in this case means when there is no more lines. So if you wanna check if a line is empty the `(line = sr.ReadLine()) != null` won't work. You can do it this way, although there are many other ways:

```
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    if (!line.Trim().Equals("")) {
        // Do something 
    }
}
```