# What's the difference between using EndOfStream and checking for null?

Tags: c#, while-loop, stream, null

I am in the process of writing a large application which involves a bit of streaming from either a process or file streams. I have 2 examples below of different ways to detect the end of a stream. I was curious as to what the difference is and which one is best to use? Is there any difference in efficiency or performance? Also, in the .NET reference guide, I noticed they check for null in methods such as `ReadAllLines` which streams from a file (similar to Example 2 below), so why don't they use `EndOfStream`?

**Example 1:**

```
...
StreamReader std_out = myProcess.StandardOutput;

while (!std_out.EndOfStream)
{
    string rLine = std_out.ReadLine();
    //Do something...
}
...
```

**Example 2:**

```
...
string rLine;
StreamReader std_out = myProcess.StandardOutput;

while ((rLine = std_out.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    //Do something...
}
...
```

Cheers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [check for null and end of stream in same statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763353/check-for-null-and-end-of-stream-in-same-statement)

Comment: Basically checking for EndOfStream is unnecessary because it will return `null` if it's at the end of the Stream anyway.. so just check for `while ((line = std_out.ReadLine()) != null)`

Comment: @DJ KRAZE I had a look at that before I posted, but it didn't really answer my question. Basically, I wanted to know the difference of using either one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no practical difference. In spite of how the documentation reads, `EndOfStream` only returns `true` when the current *buffered* stream position is at the end of the stream (i.e. when you've actually read all of the text).

So it comes down to which one looks better to you and/or which one fits better in the structure of the code you're writing.